# calling Objective-C super class implementation without overridden methods

Tags: objective-c, overriding, subclass, super

it seem like when messaging a super class from a subclass that has overridden some methods, you can't get the "original" implementation by just using super. any work arounds or should i init that super class?

here some code showing what i mean:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject

- (void)method1;

@end


@implementation ClassA

- (void)method1
{
    [self method2];
}

- (void)method2
{
    NSLog(@"Hello it's ClassA");
}

@end


@interface ClassB : ClassA

- (void)method3;

@end


@implementation ClassB

- (void)method2  // overriding method2
{
    NSLog(@"Hello it's ClassB");
}

- (void)method3
{
    [self method1]; // logs "Hello it's Class B" as expected
    [super method1]; // still logs "Hello it's ClassB" instead of "Hello it's ClassA”!?
}

@end
```

thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: The problem is self is still a ClassB even when you called one of ClassA's methods. One solution I can think of is using introspection in method1 to check if it is a ClassA or child of ClassA

Answer (score 2):

It is behaving as expected;   you've instantiated an instance of `ClassB` and, this, when `method1` calls `[self method2]`, the method dispatch follows the normal lookup path.  `self` is an instance of `ClassB`.

Copy/paste this into all your methods:

```
NSLog(@"%s %p %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, self, self);
```

That should make it clear what is going on.

> any work arounds?

Yes, don't do this as it is poor design.    A superclass second guessing inheritance is a sure fire way to end up with an unmaintainable mess of a code base.

Comment: what if method2 was public and i call it directly from a subclass? would that still be bad practice even if i never instantiate ClassA?